# Docker compose mysql reachable on port 3306

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

How can i make the mysql database in this docker-compose reachable from "outside" - meaning that i can connect with a database administration tool for example on port 3306:

```
wordpress:
 build: /Users/FabianL/wp-docker/
 container_name: "kr-wp-container"
 links:
   - db:mysql
 ports:
   - 8080:80
   - 3306:3306
db:
 image: mysql
 environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: biersaufen
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have opened port 8080 and 3306 from container "wordpress" and none from container "db"

Change your compose file to:

```
wordpress:
 build: /Users/FabianL/wp-docker/
 container_name: "kr-wp-container"
 links:
   - db:mysql
 ports:
   - 8080:80
db:
 image: mysql
 environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: biersaufen
 ports:
   - 3306:3306
```